# Can I use "ID of resouce group" or "ID of data source" as a variable on Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

Creating Azure Service Endpoint using Terraform. The code is as follows.

- main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example" {
  for_each = var.service_endpoint
  name                = var.service_endpoint_policy_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  location            = var.location

  definition {
    name        = each.value.name
    description = each.value.description
    service     = each.value.service
    service_resources = each.value.service_resources
  }
}
```

- var.tf

```
#################################
# service endpoint storage policy
#################################
variable "service_endpoint_policy_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "example-policy"
}

variable "service_endpoint" {
  type = map(object({
      name       = string,
      description       = string,
      service  = string,
      service_resources = list(string)
    }))

    default = {
      def1 = {
        name = "name1"
        description = "definition1"
        service = "Global"
        service_resources = [
          "/services/Azure",
          "/services/Azure/Batch",
          "/services/Azure/DataFactory",
          "/services/Azure/MachineLearning",
          "/services/Azure/ManagedInstance",
          "/services/Azure/WebPI",
      ]
    }
      def2 = {
        name = "name2"
        description = "definition2"
        service = "Microsoft.Storage"
        service_resources = [
          "azurerm_resource_group.example.id",   <===== this configuration
          "azurerm_storage_account.example.id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- description:
  This causes an error that "azurerm_resource_group.example.id " and "azurerm_storage_account.example.id " are not found. Is there a way to use the above "id" as a variable? I don't want to increase the definition block on main.tf .
- error
  [image]
- error message

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Can not parse "definition.0.service_resources.0" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.id": invalid URI for request
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Can not parse "definition.0.service_resources.0" as a management group id: Unable to parse Management Group ID "data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.id"
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
│
╵
╷
│ Error: expected definition.0.service_resources.0 to be one of ["/services/Azure" "/services/Azure/Batch" "/services/Azure/DataFactory" "/services/Azure/MachineLearning" "/services/Azure/ManagedInstance" "/services/Azure/WebPI"], got data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.id
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Can not parse "definition.0.service_resources.1" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "data.azurerm_storage_account.storagedata.id": invalid URI for request
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Can not parse "definition.0.service_resources.1" as a management group id: Unable to parse Management Group ID "data.azurerm_storage_account.storagedata.id"
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
│
╵
╷
│ Error: expected definition.0.service_resources.1 to be one of ["/services/Azure" "/services/Azure/Batch" "/services/Azure/DataFactory" "/services/Azure/MachineLearning" "/services/Azure/ManagedInstance" "/services/Azure/WebPI"], got data.azurerm_storage_account.storagedata.id
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.example["def2"],
│   on service_endpoint.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example":
│   21:     service_resources = each.value.service_resources
```

Comment: Please provide the error info in text format

Comment: Exported resource attributes are to be used directly, and not through variable input values as an intermediary (especially defaults). If your version of Terraform is recent, then you could use https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes as a path forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to Provision Azure Service Endpoint using Terraform and I was able to achieve the requirement successfully.

The error messages indicate that Terraform cannot parse `"azurerm_resource_group.example.id"` and `"azurerm_storage_account.example.id"` as valid Azure resource IDs within the `service_resources` list. This is because these references are being treated as literal strings, not as Terraform interpolations.

The `service_resources` attribute expects a list of Azure resource IDs in a specific format. Directly referencing Terraform resource IDs as strings doesn't meet this format.

To overcome these ensure that the resources (`azurerm_resource_group` and `azurerm_storage_account`) are defined in your Terraform configuration.

Before going to the configuration make a note of two main points before declaring services

1. **For certain services (like `Microsoft.Storage` in `def2`)**: Azure expects resource names to include 'subscriptions' and follow specific formats (like `/subscriptions/*`, `/subscriptions/*/resourcegroups/*`, etc.).
2. **For other services (like the global services in `def1`)**: Azure expects global service aliases (like `/services/Azure`, `/services/Azure/Batch`, etc.) and not specific resource paths.

**My terraform configuration:**

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vksb"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "demovkstoracc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "example" {
  for_each = var.service_endpoint
  name                = var.service_endpoint_policy_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = var.location

  definition {
    name        = each.value.name
    description = each.value.description
    service     = each.value.service
    service_resources = [
      for resource in each.value.service_resources : 
        resource == "resource_group" ? azurerm_resource_group.example.id : 
        resource == "storage_account" ? azurerm_storage_account.example.id : resource
    ]
  }
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
# Variable for Service Endpoint Policy Name
variable "service_endpoint_policy_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "demovkkk-policy"
}

# Variable for Azure region location
variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region where to deploy the resources."
  type        = string
  default     = "West Europe" # Modify this to your desired Azure region
}

# Variable for Service Endpoints
variable "service_endpoint" {
  type = map(object({
    name              = string
    description       = string
    service           = string
    service_resources = list(string)
  }))

  default = {
    def1 = {
      name = "name1"
      description = "definition1"
      service = "Global"
      service_resources = [
        "/services/Azure",
        "/services/Azure/Batch",
      ]
    },
    def2 = {
      name = "name2"
      description = "definition2"
      service = "Microsoft.Storage"
      service_resources = [
        // Specific Azure resource paths in the supported format
        "/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/resourcegroups/your-resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Storage",
        "/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/resourcegroups/your-resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Network",
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

**Output.tf:**

```
output "resource_group_id" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
}

output "storage_account_id" {
  value = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you see that an alias is added in Portal? In my case, no aliases are added.